# How to configure an xcode project to work nicely with SVN?

Tags: xcode

I'm just getting started with xcode. I created a sample new project, and would like to import it into my svn repository. I configured xcode to be aware of my repository, and xcode claims the it has successfully authenticated the connection.

I cannot, however, seem to figure out how to get my actual xcode project to manage its source in the repository. I select Project Settings -> SCM Repository -> "myrepository". But that doesn't seem to have accomplished anything. When I try to "commit entire project", xcode tells me: "/Users/me/Documents/test1" is not a working copy.

Any ideas? I'm probably missing something obvious, right?

Comment: XCODE-- > preferences --> Accounts

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out your subversion repository folder for your project to your local directory first?

If not, it's not really a working copy at all. A "working copy" is a local checkout of a repository folder, tracked using hidden .svn folders.

If you haven't checked out a repository folder, all you have is a folder. Subversion won't be able to handle that at all.

I suggest you read the [Subversion e-book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/index.html), and specifically the part about [working copies](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.wc).

Comment: Yep, I know all about svn administration (used to run one, in fact). The problem is that xcode is really poorly integrated with SVN. I can't figure out how to create a project and then manage it correctly somewhere in an existing SVN repository. According to other docs, xcode isn't capable of initially importing the project--you have to do that manually (done!). But even having done that, I can't seem to get the project configured to work right (!). Argh.

Comment: "svn import" adds the contents of a directory to the repository, but it doesn't turn the imported directory into a working copy. After importing, you need to move the project directory out of the way and do a fresh checkout from the repository. The resulting directory will be a working copy.

Comment: This seemed a bit odd to me as well, becuase I'm used to binding a project to source control, but it seems there is not manual binding of a project in xcode, you just bind to where you check out from.